# How to work FormGroup.valueChanges with pairwise() pipe?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I have the filters form which triggering requests by `valueChanges`. To get rid of redundant requests I'm using `pipe(pairwise())` for matching previous and next values. But I occur on strange behavior - in first filter change event, not emitting:

```
  private createFilters(): void {
    this.filters = new FormGroup({
      from: new FormControl(new Date(moment().startOf('week').format())),
      to: new FormControl(new Date()),
      type: new FormControl(null),
      user: new FormControl(null),
      currency: new FormControl(null),
      strategy: new FormControl(null),
      instance: new FormControl(null),
      account: new FormControl(null),
      symbol: new FormControl(null),
    });
    this.filters.markAllAsTouched();
    this.filters.markAsDirty();
  }

  private subscribeFilters(): void {
    this.filters.valueChanges
      .pipe(pairwise())
      .subscribe(([prev, next]: [any, any]) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(prev) !== JSON.stringify(next)) {
          this.loadPage();
        }
      });
  }
```

I check the problem in `JSON.stringify(prev) !== JSON.stringify(next)` but event just not triggering.

If I use `valueChanges` without `pairwise` event triggering always:

```
  private subscribeFilters(): void {
    this.filters.valueChanges
      .subscribe(() => {
        this.loadPage();
      });
  }
```

Why `valueChanges` with `pairwise` not triggering first filter change only from second change, and how to fix it?

Angular 8 version.

Comment: Pairing `pairwise()` with `startWith()` operator should help

Comment: Yes, add `startWith(this.filters.value)` operator before `pairwise` operator would work

Comment: @htn yes, it's work! Thank you!

Comment: yurzui answer should be accepted as correct answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `pairwise` it will wait for 2 values emitted, this can be harmful if you have any validation in form value changes events as the question displays.

To avoid any kind of errand behaviour in the event the best to use `startWith`.

Example:

```
control.valueChanges.pipe(
  debounceTime(500),
  distinctUntilChanged(),
  startWith(control.value),
  pairwise()).subscribe(([prev, next]) => {
    control.patchValue(prev); }
```

Here you can find the documentation for pairWise: [pairWise](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/pairwise) and [startWith](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith) and another example not using formControls: [example2](https://thecompetentdev.com/weeklyjstips/tips/24_pairwise_startwith/)

This is based on the answer in the comment done by yurzui